# UI Automation with steam client

Tags: python, c#, automation, coded-ui-tests, steam

Is it possible to Automate the Steam Client? I want create app that auto login in steam account, mb launch game or smth other with steam client, I have not found any library that could manage the steam window by id, click btns or other staff

Comment: This question is off topic and will likely be closed (but you're probably looking for something like AutoHotKey)

Comment: Steam can create a desktop shortcut for a game, I think it uses a "steam:" uri handler, which you can probably run directly.

Comment: Here's the list of supported commands https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol